# android studio intent background color text size change

Tags: android, android-intent, text, colors, background

Before I click on the button Contacts List the color background is red.When I click  the button ContacList the procedure callContacts is called and the contact list (already constructed in emulator) is loaded in a new screen, but with WHITE BACKGROUND. This works properly.
My question is how to change the background to yellow or red (it is now unfortunately white) and the text size of contacts in the new screen.
I would like to stress the change in background color and size from the initial screen(red background, small text size).
Thanks

```
package callcontactlist.example.com.callcontactlist;


import static android.content.Intent.ACTION_EDIT;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    {
        private final  int PICK_CONTACT = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


           View view1;
           view1 = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
           view1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
       }


public void callContacts(View view)
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
       startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT );

    }
}
```

Comment: view1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red); should give you a hint of what to do

Comment: This not working . The backgound initially is red but  when contacts is loaded becomes white

Comment: have you explicitly tried to call that function after loading contacts?

Comment: I try to put view1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red); in different line of the code but the screen with contacts remain with white background. When I return to the initial screen with button the background have changed, but my question is how to change the background of contacts .